# Dirac Delta function with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I tried to plot the Dirac Delta rectangular function in Python 2.7 code such that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QALGy.png)

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ddf(x,sig):
    if -(1/(2*sig))<=x and x<=(1/(2*sig)):
        val=sig
    else:
        val=0
    return val

X=np.linspace(-5,5,1000)

for sig in np.arange(1,5,0.1):
    plt.cla()
    plt.grid()
    plt.title('Dirac Delta function',size=20)
    plt.xlabel('X values',size=10)
    plt.ylabel("Dirac Delta functions' values",size=10)
    plt.ylim(0,1)
    plt.plot(X,ddf(X,sig),color='black')
    plt.pause(0.5)

plt.show()
```

But when I ran the code it gave the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Shubhadeep/Desktop/dff.py", line 22, in <module>
    plt.plot(X,ddf(X,sig),color='black')
  File "c:/Users/Shubhadeep/Desktop/dff.py", line 7, in ddf
    if -(1/(2*sig))<=x and x<=(1/(2*sig)):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: @khelwood can you please solve this?

Comment: Have you read the error message and tried its suggestions?

Comment: treat the two conditions (greater than a value and less than a value) as 0 and 1, then use multiplication to take advantage of element-wise multiplication: `return (-(1/(2*sig))<=x) * (x<=(1/(2*sig))) * sig`

Comment: What about int(i == j)

Answer (score 3):

As the error states, you cannot compare single number to an array. Here is a solution for it:

```
def ddf(x,sig):
    val = np.zeros_like(x)
    val[(-(1/(2*sig))<=x) & (x<=(1/(2*sig)))] = 1
    return val
```

output sample:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the function, you are comparing list `x` to a float `sig`. One solution would be to slightly modify the function such that it evaluates the values in `x` one-by-one, and then append the evaluation in a new list that will be returned by the function:

```
def ddf(x,sig):

   val = []  
   for i in x:
       if -(1/(2*sig))<=i and i<=(1/(2*sig)):
           val.append(sig)
       else:
           val.append(0)
   return val
```